# Installing Perf Tools with Custom Kernel

Tags: kernel

Getting these kernel files from **kernel.ubuntu.com**:

```
linux-headers-4.9.5-040905_4.9.5-040905.201701200532_all.deb
linux-headers-4.9.5-040905-generic_4.9.5-040905.201701200532_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.9.5-040905-generic_4.9.5-040905.201701200532_amd64.deb
```

And running:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.9.5-040905* linux-image-4.9.5-040905*
```

I get:

```
$ uname -r
4.9.5-040905-generic
```

So, this fails:

```
$ perf

    WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.9.5-040905

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic
```

Installing also fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-4.9.5-040905-generic'
```

I know it's probably becuase that set of tools doesn't exist in apt.  When is the timeline for getting 4.9 linux-tools in apt assuming it's not there?  What's a better workflow if you want the 4.9 kernel?

Comment: It's there for zesty: http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/linux-tools-4.9.0-12

Comment: How do I search that with aptitude?  Add the zesty packages somehow?  Or update to it?